# Print part of a randomForest object output

Tags: r

After running a `randomForest`, I have an object `RF` that contains a bunch of info.  If I highlite the objects name and hit `CTRL + R`, I get the following:

```
> RF
    Call:
     randomForest(x = iris[-5], iris[5],      ntree = 50, sampsize = c(100), importance = TRUE,      do.trace = F, forest = TRUE) 
                   Type of random forest: regression
                         Number of trees: 50
    No. of variables tried at each split: 2

              Mean of squared residuals: 0.03852423
                        % Var explained: 13.13
```

My question is how would I just print the last line (% Var explained: 13.13)?
I know for some functions there is a call like `hist$breaks` that will give a specific part of the object.  I can't find anything similar for this object.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The % variance explained is supposed to be analogous to an R^2 type value. If you look at `?randomForest` you'll see that one of the values in the object is accessed via `$rsq`. Just multiply that by 100.